# Summation calculus differentiation problem

Tags: calculus, derivatives, summation

I am new in calculus. So it will be helpful if anyone solve it and give some hint how it works.

$$E = \frac{1}{3} \sum_{i=1}^3 (mx_i+c-y_i)^2$$

Then what will be $\frac{dE}{dm}$ and $\frac{dE}{dc}$?

Thanks.

Comment: I think so..Is it wrong??

Comment: Is it the summation that is causing you trouble? Remember that differentiation is *distributive* so $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\sum_i f_i(x)=\sum_i \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} f_i(x)$.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add 1/3. Yep, summation is making troubles here. After add 1/3, it will also be same. right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\frac{dE}{dm} & =\sum_{i=1}^3 \frac{2}{3}x_i(mx_i+c-y_i) \\
\frac{dE}{dc} & = \sum_{i=1}^3 \frac{2}{3}(mx_i+c-y_i)
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But what if I add 1/3 before summation. Sorry I forgot that.

Comment: Yes, then you would have to multiply both results by one third.